# How do I produce a list of installed Android apps with root access?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, su

I know how to detect whether an Android device has root access as below:

```
public class RootUtil {
    public static boolean isDeviceRooted() {
        return checkRootMethod1() || checkRootMethod2() || checkRootMethod3();
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod1() {
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod2() {
        String[] paths = { "/system/app/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su", "/system/xbin/su", "/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su",
                "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su" };
        for (String path : paths) {
            if (new File(path).exists()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod3() {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/which", "su" });
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            if (in.readLine() != null) return true;
            return false;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (process != null) process.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

And I also know how to detect whether my particular android app has root access as below:

```
Process p; 
try { 
   // Preform su to get root privledges
   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 

   // Attempt to write a file to a root-only 
   DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream()); 
   os.writeBytes("echo \"Do I have root?\" >/system/sd/temporary.txt\n");

   // Close the terminal
   os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
   os.flush(); 
   try { 
      p.waitFor(); 
           if (p.exitValue() != 255) { 
              // TODO Code to run on success
              toastMessage("root");
           } 
           else { 
               // TODO Code to run on unsuccessful
               toastMessage("not root");    
           } 
   } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
      // TODO Code to run in interrupted exception
       toastMessage("not root"); 
   } 
} catch (IOException e) { 
   // TODO Code to run in input/output exception
    toastMessage("not root"); 
}
```

But, How do I produce a list of **all** (not just the ones I've created) installed Android apps with root access?